# Upload gojson file at codeigniter

Tags: php, html, json, codeigniter, geojson

I want to test some (upload file) code in codeigniter.
(Note: This is an image upload code and this working fine)
But, I want to try to upload other file format (**test.geojson**)
So I add some line to the allowed_types at the controller to this:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|geojson|GEOJSON';
```

and when i try to run this, the upload file is not working and give me this error [image]

I try to read the codeigniter documentation and not found anything about the list of (**filetype/allowed_types**)

So, how do I do to make this upload code to accept the geojson format?

This is the controller method:

```
public function update_pict()
    {
        $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $img = $_FILES['gambar']['name'];

        $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/img/profil/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|geojson|GEOJSON';
        $config['file_name'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $config['file_ext_tolower'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('gambar')) {
            $notif = array(
                'status' => "gagal",
                'message' => $this->upload->display_errors(),
            );

            $this->session->set_flashdata($notif);
            redirect('profil/' . $this->session->userdata('username'));
        } else {
            $data = array('path' => $this->upload->data('file_name'));
            $notif = array(
                'status' => "berhasil",
                'message' => "Foto profil berhasil diperbarui",
            );

            $this->session->set_flashdata($notif);
            $this->M_profil->replace_pict($id, $data, 'user');
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('profil/' . $this->session->userdata('username'));
        }
    }
```

This is the view modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('Profil/update_pict') ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="gambar" class="gambar">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></button>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

Thx before.

*edit : my upload file is working with this code

```
$config['allowed_types'] = '*';
```

This code is allowing all type data format. which mean this is not the best solution to my problem.
I try to edit the mimes at config to, and add this line

```
'geojson' => array('application/vnd.geo+json', 'application/geo+json')
```

and not working,
Is there any method to just allow the spesific format(**geojson**) on this code?

Comment: you can try just typing `$config['allowed_types'] = 'geojson|GEOJSON';` or you can see this quiestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272982/problems-with-codeigniter-and-allowed-types

Comment: nope, not working

Comment: Put the file you are using for testing somewhere accessible to a php or codeigniter script. Run: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php. And see what mime you get. Add that to your mimes array, or if it already exists as I doubt php will pick up on this being anywhere near a standard mime format (I've never heard of it before - what are we going to have .dbjson .crazyjson next?) add whatever corresponding mime type to the allowed string.